# Parameters not showing up in valid apiary document in api blueprint

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

Like the title says. It works if I change `+ Parameters` to `+ Attributes` but I want to do this the right way so I can try to get `dredd` working and added to ci.when I'm done.

From all the docs this should be working

[image: screenshot of fail]

Answer (score 0):

The Blueprint might be valid, but Parameters defined under Request were never rendered. If you move them to Resource (uri) or Transaction (method) level—it works as expected.